# Count Previous Days Excluding Weekends

Tags: time, label, pine-script, increment, pine-script-v5

This script has two incremental issues,

1. [ ] Swap Increments?: Counts all previous days including weekends yet increments are incorrect as labels are shown with higher increments.
   (7 DH 450.00), (6 DH 440.00), (5 DH 420.00), (4 DH 410.00), (1 DH 430.00)
2. [✓] Swap Increments?: Counts all previous market session days yet prices are incorrect as labels are all shown with the same price.
   (4 DH 430.00), (3 DH 430.00), (2 DH 430.00), (1 DH 430.00), (0 DH 430.00)

Here's a visual difference between both increments
https://imgur.com/a/MNX7p7p

```
//@version=5
indicator('Lines & Labels', 'LL', overlay=true, max_lines_count=100, max_labels_count=100)

Levels=input(true, 'Show Levels?', group='Levels', inline='1')
LL=input.int(5, '', minval=1, step=1, group='Levels', inline='1')
ShowBC=input(true, 'Swap Colors?', group='Levels', inline='2')
BC=input(color.rgb(0, 0, 0), '', group='Levels', inline='2')
DHColor=input(color.rgb(0, 150, 136), '', group='Levels', inline='2')
Extra=input(false, 'Swap Increments?', group='Levels')
T(X, T) => str.tostring(X, T)
TX(COLOR) => ShowBC ? BC : COLOR
BG(COLOR) => ShowBC ? COLOR : BC
DD=str.format_time(last_bar_index - time, 'd ')
[DT, DH, DB]=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [time, high, barstate.islast], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)
DTC=DT != DT[1]
L() => bar_index + 10
var HIGH=array.new_float(1)
LVL(bool YES, int LookBack, float Highs, color HighColor) => 
    var line H1=na
    var label H2=na
    var H3=array.new_line()
    var H4=array.new_label()
    END=true ? L() : bar_index
    if YES
        line.set_x2(H1, END)
        label.set_x(H2, END)
        if Extra
            ExtraCount=array.size(H4)
            for i = 0 to ExtraCount > 0 ? ExtraCount -1 : na
                Count=ExtraCount -1 -i
                label.set_text(array.get(H4, i), T(Count, '0') + ' DH | ' + T(Highs, '0.00'))
        H1 := line.new(bar_index, Highs, bar_index, Highs, color=HighColor, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
        H2 := label.new(na, Highs, text=DD + 'DH | ' + T(Highs, '0.00'), color=BG(HighColor), textcolor=TX(HighColor), style=label.style_label_left, size=size.small)
        array.push(H3, H1)
        array.push(H4, H2)
        if array.size(H3) > LookBack + 1
            line.delete(array.shift(H3))
            label.delete(array.shift(H4))
    if Levels and barstate.islast and array.size(H3) > 1
        for i = 0 to array.size(H3) - 2
            line.set_x2(array.get(H3, i), L())
            label.set_x(array.get(H4, i), L())
if DTC and not DB
    array.set(HIGH, 1, DH)
if Extra == false
    LVL(DTC, LL, DH, DHColor)
if Extra
    LVL(DTC, LL, DH, DHColor)
```

The simple fix would be fixing the 1st question but I've alternated between every single time variable available and still no solution.

Comment: The issue is not clear to me. Could you please explain how it should work?

Comment: I want to count previous days without using weekends. Days are counted two different ways yet both have one issue. One shows days counted including weekends & one shows days counted without weekends yet it shows additional numbers on label using last current price.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/MNX7p7p This shows the difference between both increments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator('Lines & Labels', 'LL', overlay=true, max_lines_count=100, max_labels_count=100)

Levels=input(true, 'Show Levels?', group='Levels', inline='1')
LL=input.int(5, '', minval=1, step=1, group='Levels', inline='1')
ShowBC=input(true, 'Swap Colors?', group='Levels', inline='2')
BC=input(color.rgb(0, 0, 0), '', group='Levels', inline='2')
var DHColor=input(color.rgb(0, 150, 136), 'DH', group='Daily', inline='D')
T(X, T) => str.tostring(X, T)
TX(COLOR) => ShowBC ? BC : COLOR
BG(COLOR) => ShowBC ? COLOR : BC
[DT, DH]=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [time, high], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)
DTC=DT != DT[1]
L() => bar_index + 10
LVL(bool YES, int LookBack, float Highs, color HighColor) => 
    var line H1=na
    var label H2=na
    var H3=array.new_line()
    var H4=array.new_label()
    if YES and Levels
        line.set_x2(H1, L())
        label.set_x(H2, L())
        for i = 0 to array.size(H4) > 0 ? array.size(H4) -1 : na
            Count=array.size(H4) -1 -i
            label.set_text(array.get(H4, i), T(Count, '0') + ' DH | ' + T(label.get_y(array.get(H4, i)), '0.00'))
        H1 := line.new(bar_index, Highs, bar_index, Highs, color=HighColor, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
        H2 := label.new(na, Highs, color=BG(HighColor), textcolor=TX(HighColor), style=label.style_label_left, size=size.small)
        array.push(H3, H1)
        array.push(H4, H2)
        if array.size(H3) > LookBack + 1
            line.delete(array.shift(H3))
            label.delete(array.shift(H4))
    if barstate.islast and array.size(H3) > 1
        for i = 0 to array.size(H3) - 2
            line.set_x2(array.get(H3, i), L())
            label.set_x(array.get(H4, i), L())
LVL(DTC, LL, DH, DHColor)
```

Price was constant since it required "label.get_y".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to exclude days...

```
string group_exclude   = "--- Exclude Day of Week"
bool exclude_sunday    = input.bool(false, "Sun", inline = group_exclude, group = group_exclude) ? dayofweek.sunday    == dayofweek : false
bool exclude_monday    = input.bool(false, "Mon", inline = group_exclude, group = group_exclude) ? dayofweek.monday    == dayofweek : false
bool exclude_tuesday   = input.bool(false, "Tue", inline = group_exclude, group = group_exclude) ? dayofweek.tuesday   == dayofweek : false
bool exclude_wednesday = input.bool(false, "Wed", inline = group_exclude, group = group_exclude) ? dayofweek.wednesday == dayofweek : false
bool exclude_thursday  = input.bool(false, "Thu", inline = group_exclude, group = group_exclude) ? dayofweek.thursday  == dayofweek : false
bool exclude_friday    = input.bool(false, "Fri", inline = group_exclude, group = group_exclude) ? dayofweek.friday    == dayofweek : false
bool exclude_saturday  = input.bool(false, "Sat", inline = group_exclude, group = group_exclude) ? dayofweek.saturday  == dayofweek : false
bool is_trading_day    = not (exclude_monday or exclude_thursday or exclude_wednesday or exclude_thursday or exclude_friday or exclude_saturday or exclude_sunday)

if is_trading_day
    ...
```

---

I found some errors in your code that you should address ...

1. `last_bar_index - time` makes no sense, you try to use a bar count and subtract UNIX time from it.
   The result will always be a negative number, cause UNIX time is a big number while bar count isn't in comparison.
2. `barstate.islast` as a parameter inside `request.*()` makes no sense either.

Comment: I'm aware using last_bar_index - time makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.. yet it shows the closest match to counting previous days as compared to using bar - bar or unix - unix which show completely different numbers, using timenow - time works yet formats current day as 31 instead of 0.